# Azure AD LDAP auth for Guest accounts

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, ldap

It is possible to authenticate over LDAP(s) (Azure AD services) for guest accounts?

For member accounts authentication working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to authenticate over LDAP(s) (Azure AD services) for guest accounts?

As suggested by [JamesHamil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/808550/azure-ad-ldap-auth-for-guest-accounts.html):

- No, it is not possible to use `LDAP auth for guest accounts`. Azure AD does not support LDAP directly and it requires you to use `Azure Active Directory Domain Services`. And it does not support guest users.